# How to build an Object array out of JSON array using Javascript overlay types?

Tags: java, json, gwt, jsni

My JSON response is an array of Object (Folder for example).
I would like to generate an array of Folder objects using Javascript overlay types.

I tried the following method:

```
public static final native Folder[] buildFoldersArray(String json) /*-{
    return eval('(' + json + ')');
}-*/;
```

And the usage:

```
Folder[] folders = Folder.buildFoldersArray(myJSON);
```

Note: Folder extends JavaScriptObject as it should.

And the error I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$ cannot be cast to [Lcom.cnario.project.client.Folder;
    at com.cnario.project.client.Folder$.buildFoldersArray(Folder.java)
    at com.cnario.project.client.view.TreeView.FillTree(TreeView.java:51)
    at com.cnario.project.client.ManageContent$1.onResponseReceived(ManageContent.java:89)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is the right way of retrieving objects array using JS Overlay types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
evaluation should return `JsArrey<E>` instead of `E[]`:

```
public static final native JsArray<Folder> buildFoldersArray(String json) /*-{      
    return eval('(' + json + ')');
}-*/;
```

Example usage:

```
JsArray<Folder> folder = Folder.buildFoldersArray(json);
item = new TreeItem(folder.get(0).getName());
```

Comment: Please do not use `eval()`! Use `JsonUtil.safeEval` instead (or `unsafeEval` if you really need to).

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, Can you please elaborate about the differences between 'eval' and 'JsonUtil.safeEval' and how to implement it? Maybe you can post a link on the subject?

Comment: The javadoc says it all: [safeToEval](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html#safeToEval%28java.lang.String%29) and [unsafeEval](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html#unsafeEval%28java.lang.String%29); otherwise, search the web for why `eval` is utterly unsecure.